# Population increase

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem is "Write a program that predicts the approximate size of a population of organisms. The application should use text boxes to allow the user to enter the starting number of organisms, the average daily population increase (as a percentage), and the number of days the organisms will be left to multiply. For example, assume the user enters the following values:

Starting number of organisms: 2

Average daily increase: 30%

Number of days to multiply: 10"

This is my code so far using for loop, I AM STUCK IN HOW TO DO THE WHILE LOOP FOR THIS QUESTION, please help:

```
organismnum = int(input("Enter the starting number of organism: "))
dailyIncrease = float(input("Enter the average daily increase (in percentage): "))
daysMultiply = int(input("Enter the number of days to multiply: "))

print("Day\t\tApproximate Population\n----\t--------------------------")
for day in range(1, daysMultiply + 1):
 if day == 1:
    population = organismnum
 else:
        population *= (1 + dailyIncrease / 100)
    print(format(day, "<5d"), format(population, "12,.2f"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work- just format the result your way:

```
organismnum = int(input("Enter the starting number of organism: "))
dailyIncrease = float(input("Enter the average daily increase (in percentage): "))
daysMultiply = int(input("Enter the number of days to multiply: "))

def predict_populations(org,inc,days):
    if days==0:
        return org
    else:
        new_org=org+org*(inc/100)
        return predict_populations(new_org,inc,days-1)

result=predict_populations(organismnum,dailyIncrease,daysMultiply)
print(result)
```

the result may be a floating number, you may 'round' it as an integer.

**Edit:**
in case of tracking all values :

```
organismnum = int(input("Enter the starting number of organism: "))
dailyIncrease = float(input('''Enter the average daily increase 
                                                    (inpercentage):'''))
daysMultiply = int(input("Enter the number of days to multiply: "))

def predict_populations(org,inc,days):
    cur_res=org
    cur_day=1

    yield cur_res

    while cur_day<=days:

        cur_res+=cur_res*(inc/100)
        cur_day+=1
        yield cur_res
    

result=list(predict_populations(organismnum,dailyIncrease,daysMultiply))

#now result is a list of your population
#if you want you can transfer that into a table or dictionary

table={day:pop for day,pop in enumerate(result)}#key=day,value=population
```

Comment: The thing is that the output needs to be a table going fro Day 1 to Day 10, showing the respective population increase